# Nearest Neighbor calculation in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I'm learning how to use PostGIS and spatial databases for analysis. What I am trying to do is perform a calculation to get the distance for the nearest polygon in a file, using the edge calculation, rather than vertices.

Using [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/how-to-find-the-minimum-edge-to-edge-distance-of-polygons/3237#3237) answer from Paul Ramsey to [Finding minimum edge to edge distance of polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3214/115) which is a similar question:

> CREATE TABLE mytable_distances AS
>   SELECT a.id, b.id,
>   ST_Distance(a.geom::geography,
>   b.geom::geography) as distance FROM
>   mytable a, mytable b;

I am attempting to apply it to my spatial database. I don't understand the structure of this query though. I think `CREATE TABLE mytable_distances AS` creates a table to store the result but after this part I'm lost. Are `a` and `b` column names? If so, why would I specify two columns to calculate this?

My table is called `TestArea` and I have experimented with some basic queries successfully:

```
SELECT 
  "TestArea".hgt
FROM 
  public."TestArea"
WHERE
  "TestArea".area > 100
```

The structure of the database in PGAdmin III is as follows, with my table called `TestArea`. I'm not sure what the nearest neighbor calculation should look like using my column headers (all of these objects are polygons).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`a` and `b` are alias table names to the same table. This is effectively a [`T1 CROSS JOIN T2`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html) in DB-speak. This allows a self-join to say "how close one part is to another" in a single table.

```
SELECT 
  a.hgt AS a_hgt,
  b.hgt AS b_hgt,
  ST_Distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom) AS distance_between_a_and_b
FROM 
  public."TestArea" AS a, public."TestArea" AS b
WHERE
  a.gid < b.gid AND a.area > 100 AND b.area > 100
```

You might want to add another `WHERE` clause to limit the number of rows, e.g., add `AND ST_Distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)  < 1000.0` so that all distances are less than a kilometer (if you have projected UTM).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike. I used it, and now understand what is going on. Maybe I should ask this as a new question, but is there a way of optimizing the calculation? For example if I have 100 polygons that is 10,000 calculations. I happen to have 1,000,000 polygons and am wondering how to scale down the calculation.

Comment: that's exactly why I introduced the last `ST_Distance` filter in the `WHERE` clause .. to say that "we don't want to find distances between anything else beyond a certain distance". Were you expecting to find the [one] closest area to another? This would be indeed a slightly different query.

Comment: I thought this would only not record the values above a certain level, but that it would still calculate them. Hence my subsequent question....http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/11979/803