# Making minimal distance matrix for polygons using SpatiaLite

Tags: polygon, distance, spatialite

I have a set of polygons and I want to find minimal distances between the edge of each pair of them.

It's a similar task to
[Finding minimum edge to edge distance of polygons using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/how-to-find-the-minimum-edge-to-edge-distance-of-polygons) but how do I do it in SpatiaLite?

Answer (score 1):

The ST_Distance function in the link you referenced works the same in SpatiaLite. You can import your polygons into SpatiaLite and calculate min distances there.