# How to find a distance from a point to a polyline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Please show a sample Python code of finding a distance between a point to a polyline in QGIS.  (without any plugin)

Comment: look at [How to draw perpendicular lines in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59169/how-to-draw-perpendicular-lines-in-qgis/59196#59196)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question should mention what you have tried so far and exactly where you are having problems. "Can I have code" questions are generally not well received.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. I googled and read the api.  I guess QgsDistanceArea can be used but I'm not sure how to use it.  I also found that GRASS plugin can be used to find the distance but I don't want to use the plugin if there are another solution.