# How to get perpendicular line script to work?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to get this [script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59169/how-to-draw-perpendicular-lines-in-qgis/59196#59196) to work by @gene but I'm not sure how to load the results into QGIS. I tried to make a memory layer but not sure how to add the geometries of the point, line and the intersection point:

```
point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "point_layer", "memory")
pr = point_layer.dataProvider()
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(30,120)))

line_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "line_layer", "memory")
lr = line_layer.dataProvider()
seg = QgsFeature()
line_start = QgsPoint(50,50)
line_end = QgsPoint(100,150)
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start,line_end])

def intersect_point_to_line(point, line_start, line_end):
    magnitude2 = line_start.sqrDist(line_end)
    u = ((point.x() - line_start.x()) * (line_end.x() - line_start.x()) + (point.y() - line_start.y()) * (line_end.y() - line_start.y()))/(magnitude2)
    ix = line_start.x() + u * (line_end.x() - line_start.x())
    iy = line_start.y() + u * (line_end.y() - line_start.y())
    return QgsPoint(ix,iy) 

line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([point,intersect_point_to_line(point, line_start, line_end)])
```

I am using QGIS 2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting there! Some things to note:

- Point layer

  You defined the coordinate of the point feature but you still need to add it to the point memory layer. Also, the script uses `point` to calculate the intersection point which you would need to define. Therefore, replace `fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(30,120)))` with this:

  ```
  point = QgsPoint(30,120)
  fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))
  pr.addFeatures([fet])
  ```

---

- Line layer

  Again, you need to add the line feature to the line memory layer so replace `line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start,line_end])` with this:

  ```
  seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start, line_end]))
  lr.addFeatures([seg])
  ```

---

- Intersect layer

  Personally, I like my results to be stored in another shapefile so you could create another line memory layer to show the intersection line. You already created one so you can use the same method to create another and instead of adding coordinates, you would need to add the intersection line from the `def intersect_point_to_line` function:

  ```
  intersect_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:4326", "intersect_layer", "memory")
  ir = intersect_layer.dataProvider()
  seg = QgsFeature()
  seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([point,intersect_point_to_line(point, line_start, line_end)]))
  ir.addFeatures([seg])
  ```

---

Here is the complete script which you should be able to directly copy/paste into your **Python Console**:

```
point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326", "point_layer", "memory")
pr = point_layer.dataProvider()
fet = QgsFeature()
point = QgsPoint(30,120)
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))
pr.addFeatures([fet])

line_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:4326", "line_layer", "memory")
lr = line_layer.dataProvider()
seg = QgsFeature()
line_start = QgsPoint(50,50)
line_end = QgsPoint(100,150)
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start, line_end]))
lr.addFeatures([seg])

def intersect_point_to_line(point, line_start, line_end):
    magnitude2 = line_start.sqrDist(line_end) 
    u = ((point.x() - line_start.x()) * (line_end.x() - line_start.x()) + (point.y() - line_start.y()) * (line_end.y() - line_start.y()))/(magnitude2)
    ix = line_start.x() + u * (line_end.x() - line_start.x())
    iy = line_start.y() + u * (line_end.y() - line_start.y())
    return QgsPoint(ix,iy)
    print QgsPoint(ix,iy)

intersect_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:4326", "intersect_layer", "memory")
ir = intersect_layer.dataProvider()
seg = QgsFeature()
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([point,intersect_point_to_line(point, line_start, line_end)]))
ir.addFeatures([seg])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([point_layer, line_layer, intersect_layer])
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @user35594 - Awesome buddy, glad it works :)