# Point to line - Qwater model

Tags: qgis, point, line

I'm using EPANET in QGIS (extension QWater).
I have different layers :

- pipe network (line vector)
- household (point vector)

Firstly, I'd like to connect household automatically and perpendicularly to pipe network (create another line vector).

Is it possible?

Comment: see this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232721/87346