# How to get the shortest distance from a polyline to a set of points in Python?

Tags: python, line, google-maps, distance, google-maps-api

[image]

Here in the image, the black line is the polyline I have and the red points are the points from which I need to find the distances D1, D2, D3 and D4.

The polyline data is extracted from Google directions api.

Sample polyline:

```
o`kpBywaaMQs@y@NEBCACCa@{Ag@LUJkDfC]d@yA|CuA~E_@lDArA@tADx@JfAHZBND@JBLRATINUFE?IHs@j@kBfA_A\iAXsAP}BHKCEEIe@i@cBYk@W[WY@M?Yg@kEOw@S@E@MRcA|Ao@`A[z@@ZGVUn@yEnH[f@MKiGyEmCoBgA{@wAiAw@m@s@o@}@{@CIACWEiBQeAKm@IMD[fA~EdC
```

And, sample points:

```
18.57847, 73.74055
18.57818, 73.73683
18.58348, 73.73603
18.58022, 73.73868
```

Comment: What GIS system do you indent to use? You say python, but why python when this question is trivial for GIS software?

Comment: look at [Drawing perpendicular lines in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59196/2581)

Comment: I need the distance value of the perperdiculars from the polyline to those points.