# Projecting point on feature in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

In ArcGIS the `IProximityOperator.QueryNearestPoint` method is available to get the nearest point.

Is there any similar function available in PyQGIS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready-made solution, you need to program but it is a simple problem of analytical geometry (Nearest neighbor) and the solution was given by Paul Bourke in 1998 ([Points, lines, and planes](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/)).

Several versions of his algorithm have been proposed in various languages ​​including Python:

- [Measuring distance from a point to a line segment in Python.](http://nodedangles.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/measuring-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line-segment/)
- [Nearest neighbor between a point layer and a line layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396/nearest-neighbor-between-a-point-layer-and-a-line-layer) with [shapely](http://gispython.org/shapely/manual.html) by [scw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/143/scw)
- [How to draw perpendicular lines in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59169/how-to-draw-perpendicular-lines-in-qgis/59196#5919) with PyQGIS

The script with shapely can be easily converted to PyQGIS

1) The solution of [IProximityOperator.QueryNearestPoint Method](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/IProximityOperator_QueryNearestPoint.htm)) with ArcGIS (figure from [IProximityOperator.QueryNearestPoint Method](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/IProximityOperator_QueryNearestPoint.htm))

[image]

2) one solution with PyQGIS adapting the script of [scw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/143/scw) to PyQGIS;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I checked that reference links. But all these were seems to applicable for a line with two vertex. I am having a polyline with more vertex. If I create a loop(in programming) for each segment, then it consumes more execution time. Is there anyother option available?

Answer (score 1):

By using shapely, I accomplish this [http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html]

code snippet:

```
dist = lineStr.project(refPt)

np = lineStr.interpolate(dist) # using shapely
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spatialite [1] and its `ClosestPoint( geom1 Geometry , geom2 Geometry ) : Point`. As the docs [2] say:

> Returns the Point on geom1 that is closest to geom2.

You can try it in QGIS DB Manager connected to any Spatialite database:

```
SELECT AsText(ClosestPoint(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 0 4)') , GeomFromText('POINT(2 2)') ))
```

which returns:

```
POINT(0 2)
```

Or use it in QGIS Python console:

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2
conn = dbapi2.connect('path_to_your_database/db.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
qry = "SELECT AsText(ClosestPoint(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 0 4)'), GeomFromText('POINT(2 2)') ))"
cur.execute(qry)
cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Good luck!

[1] https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index

[2] http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.1.0.html