# Making routable graph from Point and Line shapefile using Networkx?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, networkx

I have one shapefile which consists of all the streets in the study area, and another shapefile which has points representing origins and destinations.

Is it possible to find shortest path between all origins and destinations, using the links in the link shapefile?

I primarily use Python, Networkx and QGIS for my work, so it would be great to use these tools for this task.

[image]

Comment: Is the network topology ready or do you need to still prepare it?

Comment: @underdark network is ready.

Comment: Have  you tried http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/19/a-routing-script-for-the-processing-toolbox/

Comment: @underdark I've worked with that library before. It does allow to attach nodes to graph, but it doesn't contain as many functions as networkx has, and pre/post processing steps make it usually considerably slower, when you consider the whole program. I would like to stick to networkx if possible.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `read_shp` function of NetworkX to import the shapefile into a graph model: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp.html

Comment: @scw True. but I have two shapefiles, i.e. two different graphs. I need to somehow connect the two

Comment: OK, understood. First you'll need to co-register your points to your network. I think the approach I outlined here should work: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396/nearest-neighbor-between-a-point-layer-and-a-line-layer/438#438

Comment: @scw I was going to post your answer to my question, but you beat me to it haha. Great answer ;)

Comment: @scw I modified the answer your answer and it works (well, sort of). The problem is that the connection link is a "dangling" link; not connected to graph. so i have to add an edge between intersection node and line-end, but still is pretty good. please post your answer below, then I can accept it.Thanks!

Comment: Now a few years old; I am trying to solve a very similar problem exactly the same platforms. Pep, were you able to solve with networkx? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cord_thomas I don't quite remember. But I think I did this: project the point onto the line, add that point as a vertex, create a line between the original node and the newly added one. I coded it in Python, but have no idea where it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The harder initial problem to solve is co-registering your point data with your network. These data may have come from different sources, and so some positional error is to be expected. In the absence of more complex rules governing how points should be located in the network, you can use the closest point on the network to each origin/destination as shown [in this existing answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396/nearest-neighbor-between-a-point-layer-and-a-line-layer/438#438). The challenge here is finding the nearest location along the line, not just the closest vertex:

[image: nearest-point-on-line-ex]

Once you've done that step, you should have your original network, and the newly co-registered points. From there, you can use the [nx_shp](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp.html) function of NetworkX to import the shapefile into a graph model.

And though it isn't documented, if you [peek at the source](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py), you'll see that if you create a shapefile with two layers, one of points and one of lines, it will use your points as the nodes, and the lines as the edges, which can be useful.

Comment: Great! The problem is that this intersection node is somewhere in between 2 ends of an existing edge (unless it's itself endpoint). So the best thing would be to break the edge somehow at that point, so that it becomes "attached" to the graph, and hence routable.

Comment: @Pep: right, you have a couple of options. If you're looking to build a permanent data structure, you could edit the line segment and insert that point, by adding two new segments when you find the closest one. If you just wanted to do it one-off, then compute the linear distance to each closest vertex, then do the cost path to those two locations and see which one is shorter with cost + dist_to_vertex.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 1.8 has a built-in class called qgis.networkanalysis, it has functions to tie points to lines and calculate shortest path.

Comment: But it does it implicitly, and it does not calculate the length of this connection link, which can be pretty critical in many cases.