# Calculate distance between point and linestring and how to represent that on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, point, distance, linestring

I have loaded my data with osm2pgrouting and I have my network with ways (Linestring) and nodes (Point). The problem is : I have a database of doctors addresses (point) and I should calculate the distance between these points and my ways (Linestring).

[image: Yellow points are Doctors] : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSJNL.jpg)

I am using the following query :

```
SELECT ST_Distance ( 
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(55.4504545699355 -20.8752577759738)',4326),
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(55.4748349 -27.1342723, 55.4747091 -21.1338699)',4326) )
As ST_DISTANCE;
```

But I don't think that works. I need to calculate the distance from all the doctors points and represent that in QGIS as a linestring.

Any help or advice?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the *Distance to nearest hub algorithm* from the **Processing** plugin which you could add your points  and your lines layer instead of going through a query.

[image: Distance to nearest hub]

From a couple of example layers that I have, you can get something like this:

[image: Output player for Distance to nearest hub analysis]

Then when you open up the Attributes Table for the output layer, you will be given the *HubName* and *HubDist* in whatever measurement scale you selected (in my case, meters). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's for you help. The problem is that doesn't give me the nearest line from the point. That looks like this : [link](http://i.imgur.com/bgPoPpF.png)

Comment: And I want to add this lines to my network (table : ways) to calculate the driving_distance or the shortest_path from this points with PgRouting.

Comment: For the above method, you could add a query to find and show only the minimum distance from each point to its nearest line. However, I'm not familiar with PgRouting so my apologies for that.

Answer (score 2):

With QGIS 2.16 you can use [v.net.connect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.net.html) in the processing toolbox.

This connects points to the nearest line to create a network.

Open the processing toolbox and search for v.net.connect
[image]

set the properties.  You can increase the treshold to set the max distance to look for connection.
[image]

The results:
before[image]

and after
[image]

Now you can filter the new lines and calculate the distance

Answer (score 1):

read [gis.stakexchange_same_question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396/nearest-neighbor-between-point-layer-and-line-layer)
this script is available here:
https://github.com/tomflyjc/Closest_point