# QGIS distance from points to nearest line

Tags: qgis, distance

How can I get the distances from each point at a shapefile to the nearest line from another?

I've tried to follow the directions from [Measuring the distance between lines and points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34033/measuring-the-distance-between-lines-and-points-in-qgis) and [Shortest distance from point to line (big dataset)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73584/shortest-distance-from-point-to-line-big-dataset), but both methods didn't worked.

I'm using QGis 2.4 (Chugiak)

Thanks

Comment: I think a similar question has already been asked - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107227/calculate-distance-between-point-and-linestring-and-how-to-represent-that-on-qgi/107230

Answer (score 4):

If you can't get **v.distance** to work (it should be available through the GRASS plugin), you could try the *NNJoin* plugin that I uploaded to the QGIS plugin repository recently.

<del>The NNJoin plugin does not use spatial indexes for line layers, so **it is not practical if you have large datasets**.</del>

**Edit**: *The current version of the NNJoin plugin can use spatial indexes also for polygon and line layers, so its performance has improved for large line and polygon datasets.*

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved using Geotools to write a java app