# Measure shortest distance between all points in a layer and a polygon's border line

Tags: qgis, distance, vector-layer

How do I measure the distance between all points in a vector layer and a polygon (not to the polygon centroid, but to it's border line)?

In the image points are fires and the polygon is a National Park. I need to measure how far is each fire from the park's border.

[image]

Comment: Convert the boundary of the polygon to a line https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/polygonstolines.html then use point distance using v.distance https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108658/qgis-distance-from-points-to-nearest-line to find how far each point is from the bounding line.

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelStimson! I was struggling to run NNJoin before, but converting the boundary of the polygon into a line was it! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Finding the point distance to the boundary of a polygon for points that are inside can't be done directly as the proximity tool evaluates the distance from point to polygon as 0. To find the shortest distance of a point inside a polygon to its boundary [degenerate the polygon to its bounding line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/transforming-polygon-to-linestring-in-qgis#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=Assuming%20you%27re%20using%20QGIS,the%20attributes%20of%20the%20original.), this link is different to the comment and has nice pictures.

After the polygon is reduced to its bounding line the distance can be calculated with [v.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.distance.html) and probably using [NNJoin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/) as you say but I can't attest to that having not used the NNJoin tool (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use saga snap point to line (processing). That gives you the option on moving the point or producing a line.  That line however will not be snapped because of float point errors but the distance will be good.