# Nearest distance between point and line layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, proximity, polyline-creation

I have two layers, a line and a point layer.

I need to make a line layer which connects all the points to the nearest line feature. How can I do that?

Is there a plugin available for QGIS?
This is a very important tool which is missing in QGIS.

ArcView has this tool: ["Nearest Features"](http://www.jennessent.com/arcview/nearest_features.htm)

[image]

Comment: I dont remember there is a plugin for this (but i might be wrong), but it is easily solvable with a SQL query or a few python lines of code (and preferably a spatial index!).

Comment: I dont know to write a python code, I am beginner

Comment: Look at this questions, maybe it will help you: [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59169/how-to-draw-perpendicular-lines-in-qgis, [2]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73584/shortest-distance-from-point-to-line-big-dataset, [3]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107227/calculate-distance-between-point-and-linestring-and-how-to-represent-that-on-qgi/107230

Comment: I've already looked at these posts, the first is ok, but how to make a module with this code. Where do I put this code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As an alternative, you could:

1. Use the **Convert Lines to Points** tool from:

   *Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Shapes - Points > Convert Lines to Points*

   (Add points over small distances. E.g. add a point every 1m if the overall line is 100m)

   [image: Convert lines to points]
2. Use the **Distance to nearest hub** from:

   *Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector analysis tools > Distance to nearest hub*

   (Set the parameters, using the output layer of the **Convert Lines to Points** tool as the *Destination hubs layer* and setting the *Output shape type* as **Line to hub**)

   [image: Distance to nearest hub]
3. Final result should be a line layer which connects the original points layer with the original line layer (with line-converted points):

   [image: Final result with points]

   (without line-converted points):

   [image: Final result without points]

I used QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon.

Comment: There is now a tool called "Points along geometry" in the Vector geometry menu in QGIS which does the same as the SAGA tool.

Answer (score 11):

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume we have two layers *'points'* and *'river'* with their corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to create new lines that will represent the connection between points to the nearest line features.

```sql
SELECT
    ST_ShortestLine(r.geometry, p.geometry),
    p.id AS pid,
    r.id AS rid,
    ROUND(ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(r.geometry, p.geometry)), 6) AS distance
FROM
    points AS p, river AS r
WHERE
    distance < 0.5
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    MIN(distance)
```

*Note:*

- `WHERE distance < 0.5` specifies the longest acceptable distance between point to the line feature

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output]

Comment: Note - This is a PostGIS query...

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking. however, QGIS freezes, and no layer is added after it is working again. I have a point layer with about 22.000 points. Is this probably too big?
For both files I created a spatial index and for the adding I used the provider OGR data provider. Is this correct so far? 
I'm not sure, if I actually have Postgre with PostGIS configured. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile (since QGIS 3.16), there is the new [`overlay_nearest()`](https://docs.qgis.orglatest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest) function you can use for that with QGIS expressions. For each point, 1) get the nearest line with `overlay_nearest()`, 2) get the closest point on this line to the point using [`closest_point()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_nearest#closest-point).

The expression to be used with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) look like:

```
make_line (
    $geometry,
    closest_point (
        overlay_nearest ('line', $geometry)[0],
        $geometry
    )
)
```

- Replace `line` in line 4 with the name of your line layer.

*Dotted lines to connect points to nearest lines are created with the above expression:*

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual distances added to the point geometries as a new attribute?

Comment: Yes. Add `length()` funtion to it and enclose the expression above: length ( make_line  [...] )`

Comment: However, be aware of the CRS you use to get meaningful values. E.g. don't use any mercator projections - or reproject your results using `transform()` function. See here, solution 3 for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Comment: Hi @Babel, I did try to enclose my code in the length function, however, then it doesn't work anymore, meaning, it doesn't even create the line anymore.

Comment: My code is:
```length(
make_line (
$geometry,
closest_point (overlay_nearest ('clipped_mainstreets', $geometry)[0],$geometry))
)```

Comment: Oh, and my CRS is a projected EPSG:25832

Comment: I just thought, maybe it is a problem that one of my attributes has already the name 'length' (comes from OSM).

Comment: i checked it out, by renaming the 'length' attribute to 'length_osm' but this did not change anything in the result.

Comment: If you add `length`, of course there will no line be created.  `length` calculates a measurement value, not a geometry (line - for this use the solution above). If you use the expression to create a new attribute with field calclulator, it should work. If not, please add this as a new question as here in the comments, it is not the right place. Add as many information as you have and what doesn't work - you might link to this question for context

Answer (score 2):

[The ClosestPoint](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClosestPoint/)  does what you are looking for, currently limited to selected features only. You can take a look at the code and modify it for your needs

Answer (score -2):

If you find the point over the line, the shortest point, with the coordinate 3D (X,Y,Z) you need an algorithm to calc the position over the shortest line. You can using this tool https://github.com/rafaelduartenom/findpointonline. You need postgres to execute this tool and shapefiles.