# Draw shortest line between a point and a line

Tags: qgis, distance, shortest-path, perpendicular

I am trying to draw a line between a thousands of points and a line using QGIS. I then want to carry out some calculations on the new lines to see which polygons they intersect in a different layer.

I have used NNjoin to find the shortest distance between each point and the line but I want a layer displaying these lines.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of an existing question. Did you try searching for your answer already?

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding more detail (what kind of line etc.)?

Comment: Good question, nicely explained. Why on hold?

Comment: @FelixIP is the OP drawing one line among the points, like a regression line? Or one line for each of the thousand points? Before Fezter made an edit, there was no mention of NNjoin. I don't know if Fezter inferred NNjoin or that was an edit between my initial comment and this one. And what kind of calculations for the intersections?

Comment: @shea This is what OP says: "draw a line between a thousands of points AND a line". Thus he is talking about lines connecting points (e.g. property water meters) to a line (e.g. water main). Routine task in ArcGIS, not sure about QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution might work. Using SAGA to convert line to point, and then QGIS Distance to nearest hub.

[Nearest distance between point layer and line layer, QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/nearest-distance-between-point-layer-and-line-layer-qgis)