# Distance between point and line layers & spatial index issue

Tags: qgis, distance, spatial-index, points-to-line

I am trying to compute on QGIS the distance from some clusters (ie points) to their closest road (ie lines);  no need for all combinations, just the distance from each cluster to the closest road. To do so, I saw on a forum (on [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/nearest-distance-between-point-layer-and-line-layer-qgis)) that a good method was to transform lines into points, which I did, and then to compute the distance between both point layers. Nonetheless, when trying to do the last step, I get this error :

"*/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/vector.py", line 211, in spatialindex*

*idx = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures(request))*

*Exception: unknown*"

I am using a MAC. I tried on both QGIS 2.18.2 and QGIS 3.0.3, and got the same error. I tried, as advised on a page, to export geometric attributes using MMQGIS, and then re-importing them on QGIS, but same error. I also heard that it could be useful to check the validity of points ; nonetheless as I am using all the major roads network in Africa, I get millions of points, and checking them would take hours and hours ... I tried on QGIS3 to compute the distance between points and line centers (which does not give me the answer I want, as it is not the closest distance, but I did so to check if it was working this way), and it worked well, so I guess the issue lays in the transformation of my line layer into points

**Has someone faced this issue of spatial index error, and knows what is means exactly? Is there a way to correct the points, to get rid of those not correct if this is the issue ?**

Comment: Could you provide the link to the tutorial, so people can replicate the steps you followed?

Comment: Thanks for answering :) Here is the post I followed https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/nearest-distance-between-point-layer-and-line-layer-qgis

Comment: Do you need all combinations? In other words, do you need shortest distance from each point to each line?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which stresses the importance of asking one question per Question. Please [edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: @vince Hi, alright I corrected it, sorry for this.

Comment: @kazuhito : nope I would just need the distance to the closest line, and not every combinations :) Thanks !

Comment: The question has me confused about the point "clusters".   The OP wants "...just the distance from each cluster..."  What then, defines a "cluster", and how is one cluster demarcated from all other clusters?  And once a cluster is defined, what location within the cluster should be used to calculate the distance to the nearest road: the cluster's centroid?  The nearest point within the cluster?  The farthest point within the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Collect your lines into single `Multipart` object.

1. Open the attribute table of your line layer.
2. Create a new field to group all lines. I assume you create a field `group` with all values set to `'1'`.
3. Run `Singleparts to Multipart` tool (in `Vector | Geometry Tool`).
4. Open the attribute table of newly created layer `Multipart` and check if the record (row) is only one in this layer; and there is a `group` field (it's value is `'1'` apparently).

(2) Calculate distance

1. Open the attribute table of your point layer.
2. Create a new field (integer or decimal) with following expression:

---

```
 distance(
    closest_point(geometry(get_feature('Multipart', 'group', '1')), $geometry), $geometry
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

From QGIS 3.22 you can use the `Shortest line between features` algorithm that does exactly what you want:

[image]

This is the result from a point and a line layer:

[image]

On the other hand, you can use the `QgsSpatialIndex` API to get what you want:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()

source = project.mapLayersByName('points')[0]
destination = project.mapLayersByName('streets')[0]

index = QgsSpatialIndex(QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries)
index.addFeatures(destination.getFeatures(), QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

features = []

for in_feature in source.getFeatures():

    igeom = in_feature.geometry()

    # 1 is to get only the first and closest feature
    nearest_list = index.nearestNeighbor(igeom, 1)

    request.setFilterFids(nearest_list)

    for dest_feature in destination.getFeatures(request):

        jgeom = dest_feature.geometry()

        shortest_line = igeom.shortestLine(jgeom)
        feature = QgsFeature()

        attrs = in_feature.attributes()
        attrs.extend(dest_feature.attributes())

        feature.setAttributes(attrs)
        feature.setGeometry(shortest_line)
        
        features.append(feature)
```

where `features` il the list with all the shortest lines between each point and the closest line. Then you can write all these features to a new vector layer.

Be aware if your source and destination layers have different CRS!