# Automate nearest neighbor in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am new to QGIS. With the help of videos I am able to find distance between points of one layer to points of other layers. If I need to automate this process by selecting round objects as one layer and all rectangular as other layers. How would I do it?

[image]

Any guidelines how to achieve this would be highly useful.

Comment: Try here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/nearest-distance-between-point-layer-and-line-layer-qgis

Comment: What type of "objects" do you have? Are they polygons? If your "objects" are the buildings and silos in the image you included, then you'll need to turn them into vector features first.