# Attributing distance from feature in attribute table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, distance, polygon-to-point

I have the exact same question as posted at [Attributing distance from feature in attribute table using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305693), but for ArcGIS Pro.

I would like to create a field in the point shapefile attribute table which would be each point's distance from the coastline polygon shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try using the [Near (Analysis)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) tool which:

> Calculates distance and additional proximity information between the
> input features and the closest feature in another layer or feature
> class.

I do not think that will require you to convert your coastline polygons to lines first.