# Joining hub and spoke points by lines using Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, point, proximity, polyline-creation, virtual-layer

I have two shape points as shown in image below.

- Point 1 represents the connectivity nodes (hub)
- Point 2 shows the address(spoke)

How to connect each hub (connectivity nodes) to nearest spoke(address) by a Virtual Layer approach? A hub can connect many nearest spokes at random distances say 50m.

The id,s in both point layers are combination of `strings` and `integers` as shown in image of question.For example the field " GlobalID" in both layers.

**What I tried:**

I achieve this by using [MMQGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/) as shown in image 2, but i am trying to do this with virtual layer approacch.

Practical example: Suppose an electrical pole (hub) is connecting many houses (spokes).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there are two point layers `'points_test'` (blue) and  `'random_points_test'` (orange) with its corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

### One-to-One 1:1

It is an extension to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/nearest-distance-between-point-and-line-layers-in-qgis/358235#358235).

With the following query, it is possible to connect each feature in `'points_test'` with **one** in `'random_points_test'` within the distance of less than 200000m.

```sql
SELECT ST_ShortestLine(r.geometry, p.geometry) AS geom,
       p.id AS pid,
       r.id AS rid,
       ROUND(ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(r.geometry, p.geometry)), 6) AS distance
FROM "points_test" AS p, "random_points_test" AS r
WHERE distance < 200000
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY MIN(distance)
```

The output polyline layer with its attribute table will look like:

[image: result_1]

### One-to-Many 1:N

With the following query, it is possible to connect each feature in `'points_test'` with **many** in `'random_points_test'` within the distance of less than 200000m.

```sql
SELECT make_line(r.geometry, p.geometry) AS geom,
       p.id AS pid,
       r.id AS rid,
       ST_Length(make_line(r.geometry, p.geometry)) AS distance 
FROM "points_test" AS p
CROSS JOIN "random_points_test" AS r
WHERE distance < 200000
```

The output polyline layer with its attribute table will look like:

[image: result_2]

Comment: A blue dot (hub) is only conecting single dot (spoke). I am trying to connect blue dot with multiple orange dots bases on the distance radius as also shown in image 2 in question.

Comment: See my updates, I hope it is what you need.

Comment: Great.  In my case, the id,s in both point layers are combination of strings and integers as shown in image of question. Will the above solution work for those ids? I belive the above solution is only for integer ids?

Comment: For example the field " GlobalID" in both layers in question.

Comment: Can you please extend your question with these details?

Comment: I have added the info of ids in question