# Implementing NNJoin in Python

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

I am curious to know on how to implement NNJoin into the python code. I have created a point shapefile using shapely. I have another shapefile which is a centerline and is used as a reference line. Now I want to find the shortest distance from each point to the centerline. The way which I have done so far is converted the centerline shapefile into points and used NNJoin to find the shortest distance and the nearest coordinates of the point on the centerline. I want to know as to how I can implement the NNJoin using python.

Is there a way to import NNJoin as a library and use it?

If not are there any alternatives to it which I can use?

Comment: NNJoin is a QGIS Python plugin.  If you download the plugin, you have the Python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NNjoin joins two vector layers based on nearest neighbour relationships and it use GEOS as Shapely.

In Python it is quicker to use a [Spatial Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) as [Rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/tutorial.html) (Nearest Neighbours). There are many examples of the use of this module with Shapely and Fiona on the Web and GIS SE.

A solution with Shapely (without a Spatial Index) is given in [Nearest neighbor between point layer and line layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438/2581)

And a comparison of all the Python solutions is proposed in [Benchmarking Nearest Neighbor Searches in Python](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/04/29/benchmarking-nearest-neighbor-searches-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks for the help gene, I was able to get the nearest neighbor based on your recommendation. I also tried and was able to find the nearest point using interpolation. This also gave me the coordinates of the nearest neighbor on the centerline.